# ASP.NET Ajax simultaneous PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Can I call a PageMethod and then call another PageMethod before the first has finished? Are concurrent calls to PageMethods allowed?

Thanks

AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

Calling a PageMethod from ASP.NET AJAX or jQuery, or whatever kind of javascript you're using sends an Asynchronous HTTP request (the A in AJAX), and execution of other javascript on the page can continue.  A call to an ASP PageMethod behaves no different from any other AJAX call.

You can make as many AJAX calls at once as you'd desire, and as you make the call, you will supply in some way a callback method containing javascript which will execute upon receiving a response from the server.